# Pixel plotting AND partial screen updates in SDL2

Tags: c, sdl-2

I have an existing library for 2-bit (CGA) graphics in MS-DOS, and I would like to use the same API to support graphics using the same 2-bit assets on a modern system using SDL2. Basically I want an easy way to port past and future MS-DOS projects to Linux/Windows/Mac, and maybe to develop new MS-DOS projects under Linux (because debugging under MS-DOS is a pain).

My library stores a 2-bit buffer off screen and does partial screen updates as and when required. The process for dealing with a call to a graphical operation is basically: (1) draw to the 2-bit buffer and add the screen coordinates that need updating to a list; (2) when the list reaches capacity, or an explicit update is requested, transfer the changed parts of the buffer to the screen. This works nicely and efficiently in the original MS-DOS library.

My approach with SDL has been to retain this 2-bit buffer [1], and copy updates from it (pixel by pixel, unless someone can suggest a better way) onto an SDL_Renderer, then use SDL_RenderPresent to transfer that to the screen.

The problem with this I have found, is that "The backbuffer should be considered invalidated after each present; do not assume that previous contents will exist between frames," as the documentation says. And it's right: every other frame, something goes missing from the screen [2]. The documentation recommends using SDL_RenderClear(), but this isn't suitable for my application as I do partial screen updates; everything on the screen would disappear apart from the latest update.

So using a Renderer seems to be the right way to plot pixels individually, but the Renderer doesn't like partial screen updates that I need. From what I've read, the only way to do what I want is to copy the entire 2-bit buffer to a renderer pixel-by-pixel every time there's an update (no matter how small) required to the screen. I expect this would slow things down unacceptably.

So what's the proper way to achieve what I want?

--

[1] For those who are going to ask why... Because *all* the drawing operations write to this buffer, using the same code that handles drawing operations to off-screen 2-bit bitmaps, and it will be easier to port from DOS/CGA to SDL if I keep those drawing operations the same, and just worry about SDL when I transfer this buffer's contents to the screen.

[2] Strangely, I have got the graphics to update properly by putting in a 1-second pause between each "frame", which seems to allow SDL to keep the Renderer updated after each present, for reasons I don't understand. But obviously 1fps is unsuitable, even for the turn-based games I am developing. I've tried using a SDL_PollEvent() loop in its place, but that doesn't work.

Comment: Why copy the buffer pixel by pixel, why not draw it as a single `SDL_Surface`?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I don't think SDL_Surface supports 2 bits per pixel. I haven't found anything in SDL2 that appears to support the linear 2-bit-per-pixel assets and buffers my graphical data is stored in, which is why I need to transfer them to SDL-compatible structures pixel by pixel.

Comment: There is `SDL_PIXELFORMAT_INDEX2MSB` (and `...LSB`) (which aren't documented in the wiki), so there should be native support.

Comment: Thanks @HolyBlackCat, I'll look into those (probably after the Christmas break now). I've found a stop-gap solution, but a release-quality solution would be nice and I'll keep my fingers crossed that using SDL_Surface is it.

Comment: So far I've found that SDL_PIXELFORMAT_INDEX2MSB isn't in the version of the SDL library I have. So I'm currently looking into what version of the library I need, and the best way to obtain it. I could compile from the latest github version, but I'd like to avoid that if I can find a Linux .deb package sufficiently new to obtain it.

Comment: FYI compiling from source is easy, you just need all the correct dependencies. They list the required packages for a few popular distributions somewhere in the manuals.

Comment: It looks like SDL_PIXELFORMAT_INDEX2MSB is only in SDL3. So unless I want to get into using WIP versions of the library, I'm out of luck. I'll stick with the pixel-by-pixel copy for now. It's not suitable for production use, but it's helping. I'll construct a full answer once I have it working as well as I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after a few weeks, I have the closest thing available to an answer. SDL2 doesn't support 2-bit graphics; for that I'll have to wait for SDL3.

If I need 2-bit graphics, the correct way seems to be to transfer *all* 320x200 pixels from my 2-bit back buffer to an SDL_Renderer, pixel by pixel, each time there's an update, and SDL_RenderPresent that onto my window. This is slow, but it appears to work. It runs at an acceptable speed for turn-based game at least when not running valgrind (I've not yet tried with gdb).

My library (and the CGA hardware) does support 1-bit graphics at 640x200, twice the resolution of the 2-bit graphics. So until SDL3 is properly released, I can use a workaround: force 1-bit mode and use a 1-bit SDL_Surface that SDL2 *does* support, blitting 1-bit updates from my 1-bit back buffer to the 1-bit SDL_Surface. This won't allow me to do a release quality port (i.e. in colour) for Linux/Windows but it will allow me to develop under Linux, taking advantage of the debugging tools that Linux offers.

Comment: Just to add to the above solution: this only works on some GPUs. I'm told that other GPUs that don't support 1 bit per pixel will not be able to create the 1-bit surrace, as it seems is the case on my Intel HD4000 equipped laptop.

So the absolute correct answer, if you want something that'll work universally, sadly is don't use SDL2. I'm about to try getting this to work with SDL1, which I'm told is easier to work with. Failing that, I'll go for a LInux-only sulution using Xlib. Failing *that*, I'll abandon the project.